# Analyzing a keylookup from an SQL Server Execution Plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I've got an execution plan that is showing that a large portion of the cost is within a single KeyLookup. While I know what keylookups are, and within a simple SQL statement I would be able to pick them, what I'm more struggling with is how to read exactly what indexes to create from the actual execution plan output.

In my example I have the below execution plan :

[image]

I'm unsure what columns should be within my new covering index (If I do indeed need one), and what order they should be in also. I've tried a simple non-clustered index of `Id, OccurenceDate, IsFinal` but on rerunning the (large) query I still can see the keylookup showing, this could be normal as the query optimizer is smarter than me and the clustered index is better. But I'm unsure looking at the execution plan exactly what's going on.

Note. When re-running my queries. I am clearing the query plan cache using

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
```

EDIT: Added the relevant portion of the stored procedure that is generating the execution plan below.

```
SELECT 
    ro.Id, ro.OccurrenceDate, ro.RentId, 
    'Final Rent Due', p.Id, l.Id, 0, 
    p.Title, 8, 
    @false AS IsComplete, @true AS IsOverdue, 
    @false AS IsAdvanceNotification, 0 AS TodayToDo,
    null As EndDate
FROM
    RentOccurrences ro
INNER JOIN 
    Rents r ON ro.RentId = r.Id
INNER JOIN 
    Leases l ON r.LeaseId = l.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Invoices i ON i.rentId = r.Id AND i.IsActive = 1 
               AND ro.OccurrenceDate = i.DueDate
INNER JOIN 
    Properties p ON l.PropertyId = p.Id 
INNER JOIN 
    @Temp_Table_CustomerIds c ON c.Id = p.CustomerId
WHERE 
    (p.PropertyManagerId = @CurrentUserId OR 
     r.DelegatedUserId = @CurrentUserId)
    AND r.IsActive = 'True' 
    AND l.IsActive = 'True' 
    AND p.IsActive = 'True'
    AND ro.IsFinal = 'True'
    AND @ShowFinalRents = 1
    AND i.Status = 2 
    AND i.AmountDue > 0
    AND ro.OccurrenceDate < @TodaysDate
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the query.

Comment: Is the clustered key lookup actually slow? I can't imagine a covering index improving the speed since both would include the data needed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff . I can include the query (It's a massive stored proc, so will probably need to break it down to include here), but my main question is how to read the execution plan breakdown as it pertains to keylookups. What am I looking at here? Based on only the execution plan am I able to make decisions on how to create an index?

Answer (score 0):

If your query runs frequently and really decline performance than you may need a index `on RentOccurence (OccurrenceDate asc,isFinal asc) include (pk_col)` or `on RentOccurence (OccurrenceDate asc) include (pk_col, isFinal)`. Which is better depends on statistics. You can check index statistics with recommendations using following query

```
SELECT
  migs.avg_total_user_cost * (migs.avg_user_impact / 100.0) * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) AS improvement_measure,
  'CREATE INDEX [missing_index_' + CONVERT (varchar, mig.index_group_handle) + '_' + CONVERT (varchar, mid.index_handle)
  + '_' + LEFT (PARSENAME(mid.statement, 1), 32) + ']'
  + ' ON ' + mid.statement
  + ' (' + ISNULL (mid.equality_columns,'')
    + CASE WHEN mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL AND mid.inequality_columns IS NOT NULL THEN ',' ELSE '' END
    + ISNULL (mid.inequality_columns, '')
  + ')'
  + ISNULL (' INCLUDE (' + mid.included_columns + ')', '') AS create_index_statement,
  migs.*, mid.database_id, mid.[object_id]
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups mig
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats migs ON migs.group_handle = mig.index_group_handle
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details mid ON mig.index_handle = mid.index_handle
WHERE migs.avg_total_user_cost * (migs.avg_user_impact / 100.0) * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) > 10
ORDER BY migs.avg_total_user_cost * migs.avg_user_impact * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) DESC
```